# Attempting to bundle VSCode Explorer extension with webpack for first time

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code

Attempting to implement webpack to bundle my VSCode extension and am still getting to grips with webpack.
I have followed all the steps detailed here https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension
However, when I come to try to  run the extension in development, I immediately fail on the first line of extension.ts   activate(context) inside a try catch block

```
const loggerConfig = __webpack_require__("./src sync recursive")(path.join(context.extensionPath, "log4jsconfig.json"));
```

It is reporting - message:'Cannot find module 'd:\source\test-explorer\log4jsconfig.json''

Any ideas as to what might be causing this? I have almost certainly done something wrong but I have doubled checked my changes which overall didn't amount to much.

Comment: have you got the webpack example extenstion running

Comment: No I haven't touched that as it bears no resemblance to my own extension. 
I am running Webpack 5  and from what I have read, it handles json files 'seamlessly'.
However, the line that it is objecting to in my code is this:

const loggerConfig = require(path.join(context.extensionPath, "log4jsconfig.json"));

Answer (score 0):

I had to make changes to make my json file location static as webpack doesn't support dynamic file locations.